# how to convert html table into string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have variable holding a html table. there are double quotation marks in this html table.I want to remove html tag from this table. so I applied normal string manipulation method on this variable.but it didn't work.can you help me convert it to a normal string.

here is the try I have done.here the directionDataHolder is holding the html table.

```
 var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
 tmp.innerHTML = directionDataHolder;
 var data = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
```

Comment: What did you try? Post the code.

Comment: I took that code from stackoverflow

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. Do you just want get the text of the HTML table without the HTML tags?

Comment: yeap that's I want but I can't do it, because as I think there is double quotation in that directioanDataHolder variable.

Comment: problem was solved.in order to work above code it should wrap by html and body tags.thanks all for help........:)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get just the text from an HTML table stored in a string, then probably the easiest way is to use jQuery or some other framework:

```
var tbl = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>';
var text = $(tbl).text(); // text is "Cell 1Cell 2".
```

If you want to get the text of a single cell, you can do this:

```
var text = $(tbl).find('td').eq(0).text(); // text is "Cell 1"
```

[More information on jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not so sure this is what you were asking after you edited your question.  But, these are the steps to turn HTML text into a javascript string:

1. Put a backslash in front of all single quote marks like this: `It\'s going to be hot`.
2. Remove all newlines so the HTML is all on one line.
3. Surround the remaining text with single quotes: `It\'s going to be hot`
4. Assign it to a javascript variable like this:

   `var str = 'It\'s going to be hot';`

Or, you can try [this online converter](http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/).  Paste your HTML in, pick the type of output you want and press the Convert button.